# BIGQUERY CASE Statement with Wildcard

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I write a CASE statement with a wildcard match on a column

My Ver column has values Factual,Tableau021, Tableau022

The below is not working
Open to any other workaround as well if CASE is not the right statement

```
CASE WHEN Ver = 'Tableau*' THEN 'get'
     WHEN Ver = 'Factual' THEN 'Fact' 
     ELSE '' 
     END as Ver,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL * is just another character.
If you want to use it as a wildcard expression you must use LIKE and substitute the asterisk(*) with a percent(%) character like this:

```sql
with example_data as (
    select "Tableau2" as Ver UNION ALL 
    select "test123" as Ver UNION ALL 
    select "Factual" as Ver 
)
select Ver as old_ver,
 CASE WHEN Ver like 'Tableau%' THEN 'get'
      WHEN Ver = 'Factual' THEN 'Fact' 
    ELSE '' 
    END as Ver,
from  example_data
```

This returns:

| old_ver | Ver |
| --- | --- |
| Tableau2 | get |
| test123 | '' (empty string) |
| Factual | Fact |

Answer (score 1):

In case of having more than just two search values - CASE statement can become too verbose and hard to manage. In such cases consider below option

```
with example_data as (
  select 'Tableau2' Ver union all 
  select 'test123' union all 
  select 'Factual' 
), search_values as (
  select 'Tableau%' value, 'get' result union all
  select 'Factual', 'Fact'
)
select *, (
  select result from search_values
  where Ver like value limit 1 
) result
from example_data
```